# How to query select count graded in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

i have problem query using Query Builder machine laravel

i have query:

```
select count(username) as jumlah
from (select * 
from radcheck 
group by username
order by username)as counts;
```

How i make query builder in laravel?

i try make like this, but same with count select * from radcheck.

```
  $posts = DB::table('radcheck')->select(DB::raw('count(username) as jumlah'))
            ->whereExists(function ($query) {
                $query->select('*')
                      ->from('radcheck')
                      ->groupBy('username');
            })
            ->get();
            $data= '';
      foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $data = $post->jumlah;
      }
```

How Query builder laravel from query

```
select count(username) as jumlah
    from (select * 
    from radcheck 
    group by username
    order by username)as counts;
```

Comment: What actual output do you want here?  Do you just want a count of the number of usernames, or something else?  Please show us your expected raw output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Output Count Groupby Username

Comment: No, that doesn't help.  Show us a sample _table_ with expected data.  Are you looking for a single number or something else?